# How to set title/caption of Scintilla window

Tags: winapi, mfc, title, caption, scintilla

I have created a Scintilla window using `CreateWindow()` and want to set the title dynamically as different files are loaded into it. However, `SetWindowText()` is setting the content of the edit box rather than the caption. I also tried WM_SETTEXT to the same effect.

How do I set the title of the window instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Scintilla window a top-level window with a caption? That is usually not the correct way to do things, you should create a custom container window with a caption and the Scintilla window should be a child window. This child window can take up the entire client area if required.

Using a control directly as a top-level window is not just problematic because of the caption text issue, there are also often notification messages from a control that you need to handle and these are sent to the controls parent window.

Comment: I'd have preferred avoiding the extra resources but this is fine. I can now do the other elements like status bars, etc.